# What are the data types can be used with in map data type in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

I am a newbie to Cassandra so I just need to know is it wrong if I create a table with column having map data type with timestamp. if it is wrong what are the data types that I can use with map data type?

```
CREATE TABLE login_user (
  user_name text,
  password text,
  location map<timestamp,text>,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_name)
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. I'm no expert in this area, but why don't you just *try* and see if it works?

Comment: It is too broad. Instead, I would recommend you to try to implement something that satisfies your requirements and if it doesn't work - ask a question here with what you tried and what error you got.

Comment: @john and  I already get an error saying that, Multiple markers at this line
- Column hq_status type map<timestamp, text> is not compatible
   with type map<text, text>. That is why I asked this question. If you are not interested please ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Apache documentation on the [Collections](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html?highlight=map#collections),  you can use any cql_type. The CQL type are listed [there](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html?highlight=map#grammar-token-cql_type):  Timestamp is one of them.

The following queries are working:

```
INSERT INTO login_user (user_name , password , location ) VALUES ( 'bob', 'secret', { totimestamp(now()): 'time1'} );
INSERT INTO login_user (user_name , password , location ) VALUES ( 'july', 'secret', { '2011-02-03 04:05+0000': 'time1'} );
```

You probably want to check how you insert your timestamp, it could be that the CQL interpreter believes it is a text. Check the documentation for [working with timestamp](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html?highlight=map#working-with-timestamps).

Comment: thanks a lot and it worked by the way Datastax DevCenter shows me  "dateof() function is deprecated in Cassandra 2.2.0. You are currentlyusing Cassandra 3.11.2" but the insert returns exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Ah yea. I updated the answer to use totimestamp() instead of dateof()